Get rounded corner while using a border created with clip-path
I am trying to create the following shape (https://i.sstatic.net/cZmav.png
right now i am using a clip-path to create the border, because of the corner in the bottom-right. however i am having a problem to get rounded corners on the other corners. anyone has a suggestion on how to do this? (https://i.sstatic.net/dW0L2.png)
i have tried using an svg filter but i keep getting problems with the corners
This is the code i am using right now.
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% calc(100% - 4.65rem),
    calc(100% - 3.45rem) 100%,
    0 100%,
    0 0);
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: grey;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0,
        100% 0,
        100% calc(100% - 4.65rem),
        calc(100% - 3.45rem) 100%,
        0 100%,
        0 0,
        .1rem  .1rem ,
        .1rem calc(100% - .1rem),
        calc(100% - 3.45rem - 0.04rem) calc(100% - .1rem),
        calc(100% - .1rem) calc(100% - 4.65rem - 0.04rem),
        calc(100% - .1rem) .1rem,
        .1rem .1rem);
}


Polygons don't have curves/rounded corners... you need a clip-path: path

One of the options is to use a pseudo element only for a corner in the bottom-right and create the rest of it with a regular border of the .box.
That would require some clip-path and size adjustments.


.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% calc(100% - 4.7rem),
    calc(100% - 3.45rem) 100%,
    0 100%,
    0 0);
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: grey;
  clip-path: polygon(
    100% calc(100% - 4.65rem),
    calc(100% - 3.45rem) 100%,
    calc(100% - 3.45rem - 0.04rem) calc(100% - .1rem),
    calc(100% - .1rem) calc(100% - 4.65rem - 0.04rem));
  margin: -1px;
}
<div class="box"></div>



